# python error in running n inputs processed at the same time using thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am new to python. I fetch multiple ip addresses as input from a yml file and assign it to hosts. Using for loop, I iterate through these ips. These ips are processed one by one. It will then write the result to the txt file.I want to run these inputs from for loop which should be processed at the same time and write the result in the txt file. I tried using threads but it is giving errors of writing to the file.

Here is my code:

```
import yaml
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import os
import http.client
import time
import sys
import signal
import ipaddress
from pathlib import Path
import socket
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import subprocess
from threading import Thread, Lock
import threading
import random
from _thread import start_new_thread

class heart_beat():

    #Function for writing ipv4 to a txt

    def ip4write(self,ip,name):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
        print (ip)           #check
        global ip4a
        ip4a =ip
        print("ip",ip)

        self.ipve4(ip,name)
        hbwrite.write(self,ip,name)

    #Funtion for Ipv4
    def ipve4(self,ip,name):
        try:
            global stp
            cmd = "ping -c {} -W {} {}".format(count, wait_sec, ip4a).split(' ')
            output = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode().strip()
            lines = output.split("\n")
            global roundtime_ms,packet_transmit,u
            roundtime = lines[1].split()[-2].split('=')[1]
            roundtime_ms= float(roundtime) * 1000
            packet_transmit = lines[-2].split(',')[0].split()[0]
            total = lines[-2].split(',')[3].split()[1]
            loss = lines[-2].split(',')[2].split()[0]
            timing = lines[-1].split()[3].split('/')

            status,result = subprocess.getstatusoutput("ping -c1 -w2 " + str(ip4a))
            if status == 0:
                print(str(ip4a) + " UP")
                u =" UP"
                stp = 1
        except:
            print(e)
    def fields(self):
        for item in data2:
            if item["type"] == "icmp":
                #make all variables global
                global hosts,ipv4,ipv6,count,wait_sec,schedule,enabled
                hosts = (item["host"])
                ty_name = (item["name"])
                ipv4 = (item["ipv4"])
                ipv6 = (item["ipv6"])
                timeout1 = (item["timeout"])
                timeoutt =int(timeout1.replace("s",""))
                print (timeoutt)
                fields = (item["fields"])
                l1 = []
                for key in fields:
                    lis = 'fields.' + key+':' + fields[key]
                    print (lis)
                    l1.append(lis)

                fieldcustom = ""
                for i in l1:
                    fieldcustom = fieldcustom + i + "\t\t"
                print (fieldcustom)
                enabled = (item["enabled"])
                count = 1
                wait_sec = 1
    #Beat function
    def beat(self):
        #Name for the log file
        global lock
        name = 'icmp.log'
        try:
            if(enabled == True):
                for ip in hosts:
                    if(ipv4 == True and ipv6 ==False):
                        iv = ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
                        print ("iv",iv.version)
                        if (iv.version == 4):
                            start_new_thread(self.ip4write,(ip,name))
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            print("Error")
class hbwrite():
    def write(self,ip,name):
        if(stp == 1):
            #time.sleep(input)
            text_file = open(name , "a+")
            text_file.write( "monitor.ip: " "%s"  %  str(ip) + "\t\t"  +  "monitor.status: "" %s" % u  + "\t\t" +  "monitor.id: icmp@icmp-ip@"" %s" % str(ip) + "\t\t" +  "icmp.requests:"" %s" % packet_transmit +"\t\t" +  "icmp.rtt.us:"" %s" % int(roundtime_ms) +"\t\t" +  "beat.name:"" %s" % hostname +"\t\t" +  "beat.hostname:"" %s" % hostname + "\t\t" + "beat.version:"" %s" % beatversion +"\t\t" +  "tags:"" %s" % tags + "\t\t" + " %s" % fieldcustom )
            text_file.write("\n")
            text_file.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load the YAML file in to data
    data = yaml.safe_load(open('beat.yml'))
    data2 = data.get('heartbeat.monitors')
    hb = heart_beat()
    #For setting variables with values
    hb.fields()
    hb.beat()
```

Code in YAML file:

```
heartbeat.monitors:
- type: icmp

  name: icmp
  host: ["192.168.1.9","192.168.1.36"]

  enabled: True

  #schedule: "* * * * * */5"
  schedule: "*/1 * 4 2 *"
  #schedule: "*/2 17 29 1 * *"
  ipv4: True
  ipv6: False
  #mode:

  timeout: 20s

  tags: ["res1","ip1"]
  fields:
    a: apple
    b: green
```

Error i got:

```
Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads

Thread 0x00007f9fd5ed3700 (most recent call first):
  File "stackover.py", line 27 in ip4write

Thread 0x00007f9fd66d4700 (most recent call first):
  File "stackover.py", line 30 in ip4write

Thread 0x00007f9fd6ed5700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1397 in _get_handles
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 911 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626 in check_output
  File "stackover.py", line 40 in ipve4
  File "stackover.py", line 32 in ip4write

Current thread 0x00007f9fdab47700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you post the trace of the error?

Comment: I posted the error which i got after execution

Comment: This code contains unused imports, unresolved references, varaibale definitions that are never used and it accesses items from the YAML structure that you decided not to show us for some reason. People here would have been willing to help, but if that means that we need to spend half an hour fixing the code before _fixing_ it, you're not gonna get much input. Please have a look at how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if you can make one from that code above.

Comment: I have added YAML file after the code block.Unused imports and variables will be used for upcoming function in my code.

Comment: "Your issue is not strictly related to lock stuff, but with the fact you are trying to write to a no-more-existent `stdout` with a `daemon thread`".  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323799/8460132

Comment: `timeout1 = (item["timeout"])` and `fields = (item["fields"])` are not visible in that YAML part. Code that is not used or not relevant to the problem does not belong into the question.